# .NET Core docker cloud run deployment failure. Uncaught signal: 6

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, .net-core, stripe-payments, google-cloud-run

I have a .net web api wrapped in a docker container. When running the container locally everything works fine however when i run the container in the cloud i get the following error.

> The user-provided container failed to start and listen on the port
> defined provided by the PORT=80 environment variable
>
> Default STARTUP TCP probe failed 1 time consecutively for container -
> on port 80. The instance was not started
>
> Uncaught signal: 6, pid=1, tid=1, fault_addr=0.

I have a minimal version of the api which i have running successfully in google cloud with just the program.cs with an empty startup in terms of dependencies, and with the exact same docker config, so i dont think it the docker file or anything which is the issue.  I did read somewhere that Uncaught signal: 6 is to do with background workers and process causing issues.

I am trying to run stripe, firebase-admin and google secret manager nugets so wonder if that could have something to do with it.. Anyone any ideas?

ps - i haven't injected the port variable recommended by google cloud run but ive set it to match 80, which is specified in my docker-compose file. And this works evidently in my minimal api.

[cloud run errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TxRbL.png)

[docker file and docker compose file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WHIx4.png)

Ive taken the problem from a fleshed out api to a minimal api where the problem is no longer apparent, this points to the issue being something with perhaps one of the dependencies running in clud run.. Although im not sure - like ive mentioned the full api runs fine in a local docker container

Comment: post the error in text , image is not helpful at all

Comment: Ignore Signal 6. Your container failed before that error. If you include text images, also copy and paste the text into your question. Since your container failed to start, we also need the code and deploy command. Cloud Run does not support docker-compose so remove that part from your question. If your app depends on the settings from docker-compose, that is part of your problem.

Comment: think i figure it out - yep docker compose is not needed, but further more, the https port is handled by cloud run, no need to set it on the container